# Aligning text to right side in a table html

Tags: html, salesforce, text-alignment

I am trying to align text to the right hand side in an html table. Here is code aligning text to left. This is written in a salesforce source code and being published on a webpage.

```
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
<tbody style="text-align: right;">
    <tr>
        <td colspan="1" rowspan="1" valign="bottom">
        <div><b>abcdef</b></div>
        </td>
        <td colspan="1" rowspan="1" valign="bottom">
        <div><b>abcdef?</b></div>
        </td>
        <td colspan="1" rowspan="1" valign="bottom">
        <div><b>abcdef</b></div>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
```

Comment: You can use `align="right"` attribute for the `td` tags. That might fix the issue.

Comment: I would assume, just moving `style="text-align: right;"` from `tbody` to `table` would do the trick. Have you tried this?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind to use a style sheet, you could add it like this :

```css
<style>
    table td 
    {
        text-align: right;
    }
</style>
```